# edit form with drop down in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

i have the requirement, i need to edit form , and in this edit form,course_name is coming from other table and for that there is drop down box, i m not able to get selected value from database
I have following two tables:-

```
student table                   
id  name  course_id         
 1  abc      3                   


course table
id  course_name
 1     a
 2     b
 3     c
```

this is query i have written in model

```
$sql = "SELECT students.*,course.id , course.course_name , students.id as students_id
                FROM students,course
                WHERE 
                students.course_id = course.id
                ";
```

and this is view part

```
<tr>
            <th> course </th>
            <td> 

                <SELECT name="course_name" style="width:180px;" value="<?php echo $list['course_name'] ;?>">

                <?php 
                    foreach($course as $row): ?>
                        <option 
                            <?php  if ($row['course']== $list['course_id'])
                            {
                                echo 'selected';
                            }
                            ?>>
                            <?php echo $row['course_name'];?>
                        </option> 
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </SELECT>
            </td>
            <td> <?php echo form_error('course_name'); ?> </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: $row['course'] i dont this type of coloum

Comment: @Rana Soyab this to show drop down box..its working but i m not able to show selected value

Answer (score 0):

Try `$row['course_id'] == $list['course_id']`

Comment: i think there is problem in query

Comment: $sql = "SELECT students.*, course.course_name FROM students,course WHERE students.course_id = course.id";

Answer (score 0):

**Model**

```
function get_class()
    {
       $class=$this->db->get('class_master');
       return $class->result_array();
    }
```

**Controller**

```
 $data['classes'] = $this->subject_model->get_class();
```

**view**

```
<?php

                                     $sl_class=$row['class_id'];
                                                                   foreach($classes as $class){
                                        $is_selected='';

                                        if($class['class_id']==$sl_class){
                                            $is_selected='selected';
                                        }
                                ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $class['class_id'];?>" <?php echo $is_selected;?>><?php echo $class['class_name'];?></option>
                                <?php
                                    }
                                ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need value attribute in your input select.
Assuming that $list contains the result of $query, you should try :

```
<?php 
$courses = array_column($course, 'course_name', 'id');
echo form_dropdown('course_name', $courses, $list['id'], 'style="width:180px;"');
?>
```

and remove all this :

```
<SELECT name="course_name" style="width:180px;" value="<?php echo $list['course_name'] ;?>">

                <?php 
                    foreach($course as $row): ?>
                        <option 
                            <?php  if ($row['course']== $list['course_id'])
                            {
                                echo 'selected';
                            }
                            ?>>
                            <?php echo $row['course_name'];?>
                        </option> 
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </SELECT>
```